# Correct Roman Numeral: which answer is wrong?

Tags: theory, roman-numerals

[image: music theory exercise with four chords and multiple choice answers]

I already got the answer wrong, but I wanted to know which one I got wrong...

This music theory class is driving me crazy...

Comment: Which music theory class?

Comment: For bonus points, ask your teacher why the hell they think it's okay to have parallel 5ths between the 2nd and 3rd chords.

Answer (score 1):

3 is nearly correct. Check all of the notes. There's one that's not purely in V. So the answer's not just V.

Comment: From your comment, it seems like V7 is the correct answer. But I'm counting B A F# D#. Isn't the notes of E major V7 D# F# A and C#?

Comment: @MichaelLee A V7 chord is built on the 5th note of the scale.

Comment: @MichaelLee - nothing like. The V chord in key E is not what you wrote.

Comment: Okay, I'm completely understanding something wrong, let me go back and review some material

Answer (score 0):

Answer #3 is incorrect. It's in the ballpark, but a detail was missed in your answer.

Comment: Wait, if the second chord is IV, wouldn't that make the third cord V?

Comment: @MichaelLee A clarification before I answer: what are the exact choices given for that chord?

Comment: the choices are ii V i vii* iii V7 vi IV

Comment: @MichaelLee Thanks. Sounds like you're doing some review, so I'll hold off until you've had a chance to finish.